# finding sequnce of letters increasing by one in a given string

Tags: c, string

I got a question on my HW that is finding sequences of letters increasing by one and replacing them by the character "-".
the first letter and last letter of the sequence wont be replaced only the letters between them.

For example: the input string "abcdhswxyz" will be changed to: "a-dhsw-z".

As u can see, the first sequence in the string is abcd and it has changed to a-d and the second increasing sequence is wxyz and it has changed to "w-z".

Still havent got an idea.

Comment: Start simpler, *much* simpler, by just creating a loop that loops over a string, printing all the separate characters. Then add the twist that it should check if the current character is the "next" in sequence from the previous character. Add small details like that until you have solved your assignment.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but another question, what about the edge cases, meaning that I shouldnt print the first and the last letter in a certain sequence

Comment: Once you have the basics working, _then_ consider edge cases and modify your program to suit. Write tests to verify every valid input you can imagine throwing at the program to ensure it behaves correctly. If it should handle invalid input, write tests for that too. You don't have to write a perfect program from scratch in one sitting. Development is an iterative process.